# set-cookies was blocked in subdomain (MERN)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cookies

### **Background**:

I was working on a project which included to set cookie in the user's website, I tested it in localhost and it was working properly but when I deployed it, It stopped working. I am using express.js in backend and vite.js in frontend with react and i am hosting it in a subdomain. If the information is insufficient I will provide more. Click the link to see error images

## **Error**

[error info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzsnb.png)

I have properly configured the domains and the domains are same but still it didn't worked.
here is the full image , the first set-cookie is to remove the previous cookie and the next set-cookie is to set the cookie.

[Full error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivl3I.png)

### code

```js
// create token and store cookie
    res.clearCookie(COOKIE_NAME, {
      httpOnly: true,
      domain: process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN,
      signed: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
      path: "/",
    });

    const token = createToken(user._id.toString(), user.email, "7d");
    const expires = new Date();
    expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 7);
    res.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, token, {
      path: "/",
      domain: process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN,
      expires,
      httpOnly: true,
      signed: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    });
```

### env

[env file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KntC.png)